# How do I include the Image And Other objects in codeblocks with Image magick++ API?

Tags: c++, api, image-processing, imagemagick, magick++

[image][image]I am working with Magick++ and trying to use the API with codeblocks.In the build options ,I added the linker libraries to
 (build option in my project)->linker settings-> add
and the header files to  (build option in my project)->search directories->compiler->add

```
This is my test code-
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  // Construct the image object. Seperating image construction from the
  // the read operation ensures that a failure to read the image file
  // doesn't render the image object useless.
  Image image;
  try {
    // Read a file into image object
    image.read( "logo:" );

    // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
    image.crop( Geometry(100,100, 100, 100) );

    // Write the image to a file
    image.write( "logo.png" );
  }
  catch( Exception &error_ )
    {
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
      return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

And I am getting this error-
Ps:trial is the name of codeblocks project.

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in trial (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
    obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::string const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::crop(Magick::Geometry const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|23|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::write(std::string const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|30|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|30|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'|
    ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
    ||=== Build failed: 11 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
    ||=== Build: Debug in trial (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
    obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::string const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::crop(Magick::Geometry const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|23|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::write(std::string const&)'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|30|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'|
    C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Sem4\Cs213\trial\main.cpp|30|undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'|
    ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
    ||=== Build failed: 11 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Please Help Me!!

Comment: Please show your linker settings if you can.

Comment: @MarkSetchell done

Comment: The `Search Directories` should include the path `E:\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\include`.

Comment: @emcconville please check the second screenshot ,I have already added it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have successfully compiled in Visual studio but can't get it to work in codeblocks. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @ThomasWilliams , I couldn't at that time :S